# How to recover from System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server when connection changes

Tags: c#, webclient

I have made written a c# program which is successfully connecting to the remote host with and without proxy. We work in two different networks, home and office networks, which uses proxy. Here is the code snippet.

```
while(true) {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    string result = client.UploadString(Event.GetInsertURL(), "POST", json);
    if (result.Contains("SUCCESS")) {
        // Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
    } 
  }
}
```

The above code runs in a loop to keep making the request to the same api. It is working in both the networks if the program is started in those networks. However, if I start the program in home and hibernate or sleep the computer and restart it in office, I'm getting the following exception.

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.130.141:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
```

The reason is that the connection made for first time is reused in subsequent requests. Is there any way for me to force creation of connection when I get this exception?

P.S:

Code of Event.GetInsertURL()

```
public static string GetInsertURL(){
 return "https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/"eventendpoint/v1/insertEvents";
}
```

Comment: Why not just create a connection per request? Or couldn't you just catch the exception in an outer loop, and then make a new connection and use that?

Comment: not sure how to make a new connection. It looks like it is reusing the connection even when we are creating a new webclient.

Comment: Are you sure about the connection problem? I have a feeling that the problem comes from the `Event.GetInsertURL()`. Couldn't it be that you try to resolve the url to different IPs, each being exclusive to their network?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this issue when I'm switching between network after the program has been started. The URL I'm accessing is on Internet, it can be accessed from any network. Event.GetInsertURL() is just creating a URL to my google app engine application, which is constant.

Comment: Event.GetInsertURL() will be the "connection" for the WebClient so I'm still unsure about which connection you say you keep open? Because the error might not be from the shown code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Is it possible you have some connectivity code outside the shown method (I'm thinking `persistor.RemoveBroadCastedRows` might be relevant for the exception)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Nah. Event.GetInsertURL is just returning the url string using which webclient.UploadString is trying to make a connection. The connection is getting successful if I try to make this connection in a network for the first time and continue. But if I make this connection in one network and switch to another network while running the program, from next iteration webclien.UploadString is throwing an exception. I'm able to catch it, but even subsequent calls also throw same exception. persistor.RemoveBroadCastedRows is not doing anything except removing some rows in an sqlite db.

Comment: If UploadString is throwing the exception then the error should be in the Event.GetInsertURL as it must be returning an incorrect URL properly because the code inside there doesn't handle connection shift; because you're making a new WebClient each time and disposing of the old one so what ever shift is happening should be irrelevant. You should post the code of that I think.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Add the code you asked for. As I was mentioning. It is same URL that works in both networks. But my program throws exception if we switch between networks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you have shown here. I think this is a network issue more than anything else. When you reproduce the error next, can you do a telnet to the IP address shown in the error message. E.g. 74.125.130.141:443 and post your results.

Answer (score 0):

The code already creates a new client session for each connection in `new WebClient()`.

It may be that the sleep occurs during the course of one of the sessions and then triggers the fault.

In general, any of the network methods could throw under unexpected conditions. The only real solution is to wrap the code in a try/catch block and retry under the correct conditions a few times before reporting a permanent failure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience more than knowledge:
use HttpWebRequest instead of webClient , it's just more robust.
my examples are too messy but that's the base:
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);